# vNIC disable CSV output

Tags: powercli

I am using a `powerCLI` script to disable `vNICs` on `VMs` and to export the status of `vNICs`. I am trying to export `ConnectionState`.

I am using `Get-VM $vm` | `Get-NetworkAdapter` | Select Name, ConnectionState to extract output to a CSV file.

The CSV generated has vNIC name and ConnectionState but I wish to add VM name for respective VMs. I tried various options but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an additional property available as part of the output from `Get-NetworkAdapter` called "Parent". This property should be the name of the VM.

Your command should be updated to look like:

```
Get-VM $vm | Get-NetworkAdapter | Select-Object Parent, Name, ConnectionState
```